# Задержка при клике

Tags: javascript, html, android, мобильные-приложения, native

Есть нативное приложение для андроид. Но при клике, на пример по кнопке он через пару секунд загорается и потом ещё через секунде только переходит. Как убрать такую большую задержку? `jQuery` не использую.

Решил эту проблему плагином `jester`.

Comment: Приложение на базе html? Тогда смиритесь. Вроде только в самых последних версиях webkit убрали.

Comment: А может есть какме нибуть плагины?

Comment: Пишите на нормальной java, а не поделки на Phonegap и будет все круто.

Comment: оффтоп яву ток начал учить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Планшеты событие `click` обрабатывают через некоторое время. Замените на `touchend`.

Нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы писать на `phonegap`.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Я не на фонгап пишу

Comment: Появилась новая проблема. Когда я хочу скролить и касаюсь до кнопки то после того как я убрал палец он переходит по той кнопке.

Comment: @Perkovec думаю стоит повесить touchstart на документ и при touchend проверять, совпадают ли элементы.

Comment: всмысле проверить соответствуют ли координаты touchend и touchstart если нет то раскажите подробнее

Comment: Наверно так:

    var lastTouch;
    
    $(document).on('touchstart', function(e) {
        lastTouch = e.target;
    });
    
    $(element).on('touchend', function(e) {
        if(e.target == lastTouch ) {
            //...
        }
    });

Comment: Решил эту проблему плагином jester